# Updating table in R programming, syntax

Tags: r, loops

How do I do this in R programming? Not sure why the process is hanging

```
dat <- data.frame(
  total = 10,
  expense = c(2,3,1,3,1)
)

#  total expense
#1    10       2
#2    10       3
#3    10       1
#4    10       3
#5    10       1
```

Expected output:

```
out <- data.frame(
  total = 10,
  expense = c(2,3,1,3,1),
  remaining = c(8,5,4,1,0)
)
#  total expense remaining
#1    10       2         8
#2    10       3         5
#3    10       1         4
#4    10       3         1
#5    10       1         0
```

I tried:

```
while (dat$remaining > 0)
{ dat$remaining <- dat$total - dat$expense}
```

Comment: I cannot add pictures to the question, Not sure why, which makes it hard to identify.

Comment: It's because we **strongly** discourage including images. You should include a [mcve] of your problem (including data, expected output, and actual output) as text in the question. This will let us reproduce and try to solve your problem

Comment: I.e., something like `dat <- data.frame(expense = c(2,3,1,3,1),  remaining = c(8,5,NA,NA,NA))` would be good to use rather than an image, as we can all copy and paste that.

Comment: divibisan, Got it, How do I make Tables here, Do I have to code the tables in too?

Comment: thelatemail, The table I am working on is huge, I made a sample screenshot from excel and uploaded it here.

Comment: @FirstSlack - we don't need the huge code or data, just a few simple lines like you've shown in your screenshot are fine. Just not in image form, so people can copy and paste.

Comment: Yes, Is this how it should be?

Comment: @FirstSlack - have a look at my edit and see if that matches what you want.

Comment: Yes, It looks good.

Comment: @FirstSlack - you don't have to, you will import your data from the spreadsheet or whatever. This is just for our benefit in answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially subtracting a `cum`ulative `sum` of the `dat$expense` column from the original `dat$total` value. So:

```
dat$remaining <- dat$total[1] - cumsum(dat$expense)
dat
#  total expense remaining
#1    10       2         8
#2    10       3         5
#3    10       1         4
#4    10       3         1
#5    10       1         0
```

Comment: can we use a loop to update the table? or the cumsum() is a easier solution?

Comment: @FirstSlack - you could use a loop, sure, but `cumsum` will be one statement vs. several for a loop. `cumsum` is also compiled code (probably a compiled loop!) and will run very quickly compared to manually writing a loop in R.